# pycharm venv python version weirdness

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community 2022.1 on a Linux machine. I use a Virtual Environment (venv) for my project and I'm struggling to understand how it works.

I can install packages via the PyCharm IDE, except when the package is too large I get an error:

[image]

I follow the suggestion of:

> source /home/robin/PycharmProjects/ChickenRun2/venv/bin/activate
>
> pip install torch

I get the error:

[image]

After typing:

> python -m ensure pip
>
> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
>
> pip install torch

I can install the "torch" package in the venv, however the package does not seem to be installed according to the PyCharm IDE.

[image]

I also notice something strange - the version of python according to PyCharm is:

[image]

While from the command line the python version is:

[image]

I have set the Project Interpreter under "File > Settings > Project" in PyCharm to use Base Interpreter /usr/bin/python when setting up the venv, and that is definitely python 3.10.4

However, within the IDE it is listed as Python 3.9:

[image]

While from the terminal it is shown as Python 3.10.4:

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on here? Or have a suggestion on how I can get the torch package installed so I can use it in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem of installing the torch package by using the Terminal tab at the bottom of the PyCharm IDE.

> (venv) pip install --no-cache-dir torch

[image]

I'm still confused why it is using Python 3.9 rather than Python 3.10 when Base Interpreter is /usr/bin/python which is Python 3.10.

Also I don't understand why the same thing does not work from the terminal:

> source /home/robin/PycharmProjects/ChickenRun2/venv/bin/activate
>
> pip install --no-cache-dir torch

It does not recognise pip.

But the main issue is resolved!

Comment: The issue of the versions shown by PyCharm that you mention is likely just the version written in the name being outdated because that name is just a string that might not be updated (see the linked posts of [PY-17858](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17858)). Either that or it's showing info from an outdated interpreter that should be removed and added again (but it's hard to say from the info you've included in the question, ascertaining what interpreters are available can only be done by you.)

Comment: The remaining symptoms seem to suggest one of the venvs doesn't have pip installed and after activating it the parent venv's sitepackages are shared and that's where pip will be found. But again, without more explicit info in the question this is asking for a lot of deduction and guess work from the readers...

Comment: PyCharm seems to genuinely believe it is using Python 3.9, not just an out of date string. "(venv) python --version" gives "3.9.9"; "(venv) which python" gives "/home/robin/PycharmProjects/ChickenRun2/venv/bin/python". The terminal disagrees: "/home/robin/PycharmProjects/ChickenRun2/venv/bin/python --version" gives "3.10.4". Very strange! The same issue arises if I create a brand new project with a brand new interpreter. Sorry for the lack of explicit information - I'm trying to post what I think is relevant but it is not always obvious!

Comment: Create a brand new venv in a completely different directory and indicate clearly the version of the base interpreter you're creating it from. After that's done run the test with activation, the venv version should coincide with that of the base interpreter you've created from. Following this method PyCharm always installs pip to the new venv by default, so that 1st error message about the venv not having pip already indicates something didn't go as usual. You may want to refresh the screenshots, it's not clear to me if and when you jumped over steps.

Comment: What the 5th screenshots shows is that's already the 3rd venv with the same name you've created, so try the changing the name and the path.

Comment: I think I found the problem: https://imgur.com/LH0aGsB. PyCharm interface is lying when I selected /usr/bin/python (Python 3.10) as base interpreter - it must override that.